# How to properly change the state of an element using Redux-Tollkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

DEMO - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-68usks?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/App.js

How to properly change the state of an element?

I'm learning React in practice.

I want to change the state of the `isInBasket` property on click of the "**Add to cart**" button to make the button active.
Similar to how I did for the "**Add to favorites**" button.

Sample data:

```
  {
    id: 1
    title: 'BMW',
    isFavorite: false
    isInBasket: false
  }
```

I have a product card component and a cart component.
The product card has two buttons "**add to cart**" and "**Add to favorites**".

I have two reducers, "basket" and "products".
The basket reducer contains actions that are responsible for the state of the basket (*add/remove/clear*).

***basketSlice.js***

```js
const basketSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'basket',
  initialState: {
    products: [],
    isEmpty: true,
  },
  reducers: {
    setProductToBasket: (state, action) => {
      const productOne = state?.products.find(
        (p) => p.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (!productOne) {
        state.products.push({
          ...action.payload,
          isInBasket: true,
        });
        state.isEmpty = false;
      }
    },

    removeProductFromBasket: (state, action) => {
      state.products = state?.products.filter((p) => p.id !== action.payload);
      state.products.isInBasket = !state.products.isInBasket;

      state.products.length > 0
        ? (state.isEmpty = false)
        : (state.isEmpty = true);
    },

    clearBasket: (state) => {
      state.products = [];
      state.isEmpty = !state.isEmpty;
    },
  },
});
```

There is only one "add to favorites" action in the product reducer.

***productsSlice.js***

```js
import { products } from '../data';

const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'products',
  initialState: {
    products,
  },
  reducers: {
    toggleFavoriteProduct: (state, action) => {
      const productOne = state.products.find((p) => p.id === action.payload);

      if (productOne) {
        productOne.isFavorite = !productOne.isFavorite;
      }
    },
  },
});
```

***ProductItem.js***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setProductToBasket } from '../features/basketSlice';
import { toggleFavoriteProduct } from '../features/productsSlice';

export default function ProductItem({ product }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // const { stateBasket, stateProducts } = useSelector((state) => state);

  const onAddToBasket = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    dispatch(setProductToBasket(product));
  };

  const onToggleFavorite = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    dispatch(toggleFavoriteProduct(product.id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="products-item">
      <h4>{product.title}</h4>
      <button
        className={`btn ${product.isInBasket ? 'active' : ''}`}
        onClick={onAddToBasket}
      >
        {product.isInBasket ? <></> : <></>}
      </button>
      <button
        className={`btn ${product.isFavorite ? 'active' : ''}`}
        onClick={onToggleFavorite}
      >
        {product.isFavorite ? <>❤️</> : <></>}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the product card:

- on the "add to favorites" button, I will dispatch the `toggleFavoriteProduct` action.
- on the "add to cart" button, I will dispatch the `setProductToBasket` action.

And if you look in the reducers, you can see that the `isInBasket` flag changes to `true` only for objects in the basket state, and remains `false` in products.

I'm a little confused and trying to figure out how do I change the state of the `isInBasket` flag not in the basket state (`stateBasket`), but in the products state (`stateProducts`)?
Add a new action to the product reducer, checking if this product is in the cart or not?

If I understand the concept correctly, then you can't mix entities. By this I mean that you can not access another state or am I mistaken?

What is the best way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new action in product reducer,

```
 reducers: {
    toggleFavoriteProduct: (state, action) => {
      const productOne = state.products.find((p) => p.id === action.payload);

      if (productOne) {
        productOne.isFavorite = !productOne.isFavorite;
      }
    },
// new action here
    toggleIsInBucket: (state, action) => {
      const productOne = state.products.find((p) => p.id === action.payload);
      if (productOne) {
        productOne.isInBasket = !productOne.isInBasket;
      }
    },
  },
```

Then you can dispatch that from the components,
When adding item from `<ProductItem>`

```
  const onAddToBasket = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    dispatch(setProductToBasket(product));
    dispatch(toggleIsInBasket(product.id));
  };
```

When removing the item from cart,

```
  const onRemoveProductBasket = () => {
    dispatch(removeProductFromBasket(product.id));
    dispatch(toggleIsInBucket(product.id));
  };
```

This way you are not mixing up entities but using actions to modify the two different stores.